# What method to use to fire an event after datetime is selected using datetime selector UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I came across a [datatimepicker plugin](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)

I am trying to use it in a small app that I am working on. I need to be able to enable a button after a user selects data from the picker.

What method would use to trigger some logic after the datetime was selected

Comment: Could you put some snippet code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind an event to your form input element to fire when it changes.

```
('#date').datetimepicker({
  ...

  onChangeDateTime: function(dp,$input){
     alert($input.val())
  }

  ...
});
```

Within the handler function you will probably want to implement some kind check to ensure that the value is what you want it to be before enabling the button.

Comment: Thank you for this code. You code makes since but for some reason the change event does not fire when the user select a date and time.

Comment: @MikeA no problem, I've had a look into the API for the picker you're using and it has an option to add a callback. I've edited my answer, please see if that works for you.